# How to pass value to another page using onChangeText callback function in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I just got a issue when i use react native navigator component, the thing is i have a index.ios.js which is just render the navigator scene which have a default component called default page to be displayed, in this index.ios.js also have a Navigator.NavigationBar component for the next step action. and the default component have a TextInput component for user to type sth.

So my question is i wanna check if the TextInput component(in the default page) is not null or empty when the user click the next step button in the main page, i really didn't found a way that can pass value in run-time by the onTextChange callback function, is it rewrite the Navigator component will work in this case? but i still don't know how to do it.

This stuff really stress me a lot.

[here is the UI of the demo.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbVIm.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a state in your main page, and define a function to set the state with a given value. You can pass this function to the page that has the text field. You can then call this function on the onChangeText of the text field, hence setting the state on the main page. You can then successfully check the state in the main component to check if it is empty or not.

```js
// i am assuming here that you pass the setMyText from the 'Main' component below as prop to this compoenet.
class MyTextInputComponent extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <TextInput onChangeText={this.props.setMyText} />
    )
  }
}

class Main extends Compoenent {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      myText: ''
    }
  }
  
  // you can pass this function to your component that has the text view like 'MyTextInputCompoenent' below
  setMyText = (text) => {
    this.setState({
      myText: text
    })
  }
  
  // here you can check if the this.state.myText is empty or not before continuing
  onClickNext = () => {
    if(this.state.myText) {
      // do sth
    } else {
      // do sth else
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi ,Aakash Sigdel,This works perfectly, thx very much,sorry for response so late.